# Running asp.net core Kestrel server on linux as a service

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, kestrel

I've set up an Ubuntu 18.04 Linux server, and run my ASP.NET Core 2.1 app on it using Kestrel locally and Nginx as a reverse-proxy.

When I run the app using `dotnet run` it starts up without a problem and I can access the website, but if I try to create a service per [this MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1#monitor-the-app), the server starts up normally (the same DLL, Database, etc) and seems to encounter some exceptions which when trying to access the web page.

```
    ov 14 07:43:05:       Executed action method AcademiWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Index (AcademiWeb), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in 0.4463ms.
Nov 14 07:43:05: #033[40m#033[32minfo#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[1]
Nov 14 07:43:05:       Executing ViewResult, running view Index.
Nov 14 07:43:06: #033[40m#033[32minfo#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
Nov 14 07:43:06 :       Executed action AcademiWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Index (AcademiWeb) in 151.9161ms
Nov 14 07:43:06: #033[41m#033[30mfail#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
Nov 14 07:43:06 ]:       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Nov 14 07:43:06 : System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Nov 14 07:43:06 : Parameter name: connectionString
Nov 14 07:43:06:    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
```

Is there anything I might be missing here? Something with the appsettings file? Searching online didn't come up with any relevant results.

Comment: What exceptions? Make that clear please. Kestrel has its logging, so enable it and read its log file.

Comment: I've added the exception, when it's checking the connectionString it appears to be null - probably a problem accessing the appsettings.json but I don't know why that problem would occur

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - the working directory I set in the service was of the **entire solution** and not the running **project** which contains the appsettings.json, so when it was trying to access the connectionString in it the value was null.